Custom Attributes in Java
I'm not overly familiar with Java, in C# I can declare a custom attribute for a property as follows:
Create attribute type:
public class MyCustomAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

Then decorate anything (class, method, property, ...) with the attribute:
[MyCustomAttribute(SomeProperty = "foo bar")]
public class Foo
{

}

This can then be read using reflection at runtime.
Searching shows me 'custom attributes' are something used in unit testing. Is there anything the same or similar in Java?
